# Can't set the value of textItem.contents

Tags: extendscript, photoshop-script

I am trying to write a script that will update the value of a text layer in Photoshop.

I have a layer stored in a variable `myLayer` which I log out so I know it is an `ArtLayer` with a type of `LayerKind.TEXT` and has a `textItem` object associated that has a string value in place. All as I would expect.

The documentation says that `textItem.contents` is read-write so I thought `myLayer.textItem.contents = "Hello World"` should update the value but when I try this I get `General Photoshop Error occurred. This functionality might not be available in this version of Photoshop`.

Can anyone advise on what I'm missing?

I am using Photoshop CC 2014 and the [CC 2014 Javascript Reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop_scriptref_js.pdf)

Thankyou in advance for you help :)

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to see whats going wrong when there is no code example. This works for me.

Tested in PS CC 2014  Mac OSX

```
// needs a Photoshop document with only one textlayer
var d = app.activeDocument;
var l = d.artLayers[0];
if(l.hasOwnProperty ("textItem")){
    $.writeln("yes");
    l.textItem.contents = "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I am doing. The way I get my target layer is a bit round-the-houses so perhaps I am targeting the wrong element. I'm not going to get a chance to look at this again for a few days but will report back when I have cracked it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This works in CS2: (Assuming the active layer (mylayer) is a text layer)

```
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
var myLayer= srcDoc.activeLayer;

var text = myLayer.textItem.contents;
myLayer.textItem.contents = "Hello World";
```